# Determining diameter of parachute to obtain specific landing speed of a body, with Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

An example on a physics assignment asks this question:

> NASA is preparing a probe to send to Mars. The probe weighs $40kg_f$ on Earth. As it approaches Mars, the gravitational field of Mars, which is given as $g_{mars}=3.711 m/s^2$, will pull it down. 
>   The question is, what should the diameter of the parachute be so that the probe touches the surface with a speed of $3m/s$?

Here's what's given:

- $A_{chute} = \pi \frac{D^2}{4}$
- $C_D$ (the parachute's drag coefficient) $=1.4$
- Density of Mars' atmosphere = $0.8167kg/m^3$
- Landing the probe on Mars at $3m/s$ is equivalent to dropping it from a height of $0.5 $ meters (sans parachute) on Earth.
- The problem involves a differential equation.

> Here's where I'm stuck:
>   I'm using the formula $$ m \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} \rho_{air} \space C_d A \space v^2$$
>   to solve for $A$, area. The problem is, that when the parachute is drifting down through the Martian atmosphere with the parachute deployed, it quickly meets its terminal velocity and $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$, which makes it impossible to solve for $A$. 
>   I can't find another way/formula to use to solve for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probe reaches terminal velocity when the drag force from the parachute equals the gravitational force of the planet.

You have the drag force:

$$F_{drag} = \frac{1}{2} \rho_{air} \space C_d A \space v^2$$

And you have the gravitational force:

$$F_g = m_{probe} \space g_{mars}$$

You just need to solve the equation:

$$F_{drag} = F_g$$

Where the only unknown is $A$ (you already know that you want $v = 3.0 m/s$).

P.S.: You would have probably gotten a faster response if you had placed this question in https://physics.stackexchange.com/

P.P.S.: Reading your question again it seems that your doubt came from the expression the drag force as $m \frac{d_v}{d_t}$. This expression is correct in the absence of gravity, i.e. $\frac{d_v}{d_t}$ refers to the change of velocity due to the drag force only when no other forces are acting.

Comment: Where do differential equations come into play in the answer though?

Comment: You don't need to solve any differential equation in this problem. You just need to justify that $g_{mars}$ = $\frac{d_v}{d_t}$ of your differential equation when the probe touches the surface.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand that.. what do you mean $g_{mars} = \frac{dv}{dt}$ when it touches the surface? Why not the whole time?

Comment: I say "when it touches the surface", but I mean "after it reaches terminal velocity". This includes the moment of touching the surface which is the interesting one for you.

Comment: Does this make sense: $A = \frac{\sqrt(112)}{\sqrt(\pi)}$?

Comment: According to my computations $A \approx 28.85 m^2$ which doesn't correspond to your number. How do you get such round numbers (112) from terms like $\rho = 0.8167 kg/m^3$?

Comment: I used $A = 28$ as an estimate

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the previous answer

$m_{probe} \space g_{mars}= \frac{1}{2} \rho_{air} \space C_d A \space v^2$

You could put $v=dy/dt$  to get differential equation